# REGEXP_REPLACE expression issue

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I got some sql script below to remove word between words, but it will find last occurrence of my (/hide) instead of the first occurrence. Need help to get the output as expected. Thanks.

```
select regexp_replace('(hide)it(/hide)should be show(hide)my(/hide) text',
       '^\(hide\).*\(/hide\)', '') "TESTING" 
  from dual;
```

I expect the output will be:

```
should be show text
```

but the actual output is:

```
text
```

If my data is in one of the column with datatype of clob. As currently i use below script to select. For example my table is testing_table with column of desc_str with data_type of clob which inside contain value '(hide)it(/hide)should be show(hide)my(/hide) text';

```
select trim(to_char(regexp_replace(desc_str,'^\(hide\).*\(/hide\)',''))) as desc 
  from testing_table 
 where OOE_FP_SS_ID = $id;
```

Comment: I am using the oracle sql developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '(hide)it(/hide)should be show(hide)my(/hide) text' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(col, '\(hide\)\w+\(/hide\)', '') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-------------------
should be show text

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: CLOB]**

You asked for a CLOB. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (desc_str clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('(hide)it(/hide)should be show(hide)my(/hide) text');

1 row created.

SQL> select regexp_replace(desc_str, '\(hide\)\w+\(/hide\)', '') result from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
should be show text

SQL>
```

---

Another example:

```
SQL> with test (desc_str) as
  2    (select '(hide)ItemId: 4334(/hide)|(hide)Description Item - SubType:(/hide) Name - Item|(irow)Price Value: MYR 1,668' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(desc_str, '\(hide\).+?\(/hide\)', '') result from test;
                                                ^
RESULT                                          | this question mark was missing
------------------------------------------
| Name - Item|(irow)Price Value: MYR 1,668

SQL>
```

Comment: How about if my text '(hide)it(/hide)should be show(hide)my(/hide) text' is one of the column in table with data type of clob?

Comment: Try and see what happens.

Comment: with test (col) as
(select to_char(desc_str) from testing_table where id = 6041)
select regexp_replace(col, '\(hide\)\w+\(/hide\)', '') result
from test;

Comment: i try using above code it cannot hide the word between hide

Comment: I try above data is working fine, but may i know why the data below unable to hide.
(hide)ItemId: 4334(/hide)|(hide)Description Item - SubType:(/hide) Name - Item|(irow)Price Value: MYR 1,668

Comment: Why? Because it differs from your initial sample data, so expression is now changed. I added *another example* into my answer; see how it looks.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, I had tried your solution above, but it actually the result should be "| Name - Item|(irow)Price Value: MYR 1,688", but it missing pipe (|) in front. It cannot take the value between, it directly get the value behind only.

Comment: Aha. Question mark was missing. I edited my answer and marked the spot.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, May i know where to put the question mark? I unable to see the edited answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is within "Another example", this: `'\(hide\).+?\(/hide\)'`

Comment: I able to get the value i want. Thanks for the help @Littlefoot.